# Data types in ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC models

Tags: sql, model-view-controller, types

I am extremely new to coding and have struck a problem. I am doing an ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC app. I am trying to create a model using a date column and I am not having any success. The code I am using is shown below.

My thought is that there must be a way to store a date in SQL but to no avail. Any conversation or comments great appreciated.

The error occurs on this line

```
public Date CreationDate { get; set; }
```

It will not accept `Date` as a data type.

Regards    Steve

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SalesAccount.Models
{
    public class Contract
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        **public Date CreationDate { get; set; }**
        [Required]
        public char ContractNumber { get; set; }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: .NET / C# does **NOT** have a datatype called `Date` - you always need to use `DateTime` (or `DateTimeOffset`, if the timezone info is relevant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use data type `DateTime` for that purpose instead of `Date`. In C# `Date` data type doesn't exist.

```
public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0):

using data type DateTime instead of Date
public DateTime CreationDate{get;set}

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).